# x86 assembly code to put string in EAX register

Tags: assembly, x86, system-calls, osdev

```
#define SYS_abcd abcd

#define SYSCALL1(name) \
  .globl name; \
  name: \
    mov $SYS_ ## name, %eax; \
    int $T_SYSCALL1; \
    ret

SYSCALL1(abcd)
```

The system call code that I use to handle it looks like:

```
char ptr="abcd"; 
char arg;
arg = (char*)proc->tf->eax; 
cprintf(arg); 
if(strncmp(ptr, arg, strlen(ptr)) == 0) 
    proc->tf->eax = 1; 
else { 
    cprintf("unknown call:"); 
    proc->tf->eax = -1; 
}
```

This macro, when processed, will put 'abcd' in the EAX register. But somehow I am getting a garbage value. Is there a different way to move a string to the EAX register?

Comment: You don't usually move `strings` into a register but you usually move the address of a string. It is unclear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @MichaelPetch-I m trying to make a call to a system call using the name of the system call. So I need to put the string in the eax register and use it later in the kernel code.

Comment: I'll assume this is an xv6 assignment?

Comment: What is `SYS_abcd` defined as?

Comment: In this case somewhre you would have to have `SYS_abcd` defined (probably a `#define` somewhere). Probably a constant value representing the system call number. Without seeing how you define it I can't say what should be in _EAX_

Comment: I have defined that in syscall.h as ---   # define SYS_abcd  abcd. I have to use a string rather than system call number.

Comment: ` char *ptr="abcd";
  char* arg;
  arg = (char*)proc->tf->eax;
 cprintf(arg);
  if(strncmp(ptr, arg, strlen(ptr)) == 0)
    proc->tf->eax = 1;
  else {
    cprintf("unknown call:");
    proc->tf->eax = -1;
  }`    so the cprintf give me some garbage value as :�zu

Comment: The way you defined that `SYS_abcd` to be `abcd` when finally processed the  substitution would look like `mov $abcd, %eax;` . That would move the address of label `abcd` into _EAX_.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Thanks for the help. I m not sure how can I pass the string abcd into EAX so that I can get it later in the kernel code. I have seen other system calls implementation It use process trapeframe to get the number associated with system call like this: proc->tf->eax.

Comment: You would normally put the string `abcd` in memory and pass the address of that string into _EAX_. SInce I don't know much about the requirements of your homework assignment I can't really be of much more help. Have you considered discussing this with the professor or the teacher assistants who likely know more about what is required? I can only guess that they want you to create an array of string pointers with each syscall string in it.

Comment: I am looking to pass a string to the kernel. And that string is the system call name.

Comment: Then you will want to put the string `"abcd"` in memory and then pass the address of that string through _EAX_. You are currently passing the address of the label `abcd` into _EAX_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear what the parameters of the assignment are, what can be done etc. But a quick and dirty way may be something like this:

```
#define SYSCALL1(name) \
  .globl name; \
  name: \
    mov $SYS_STR_ ## name, %eax; \
    int $T_SYSCALL1; \
    ret; \
  SYS_STR_ ## name: .asciz #name;

SYSCALL1(abcd)
```

This defines a string in memory and the **address** of that string is used as the parameter to be passed in *EAX*.

After substitution the generated code would look like:

```
.globl abcd; 
abcd: 
    mov $SYS_STR_abcd, %eax; 
    int $T_SYSCALL1; 
    ret;

SYS_STR_abcd: .asciz "abcd";
```

Passing the address of a string representing a system call is not very efficient but does appear to be what is being asked for.

Your system call code that processes the system call may need some work as well. Something like:

```
char *ptr="abcd"; 
char *arg = (char*)proc->tf->eax; 
cprintf(arg); 
if(strcmp(ptr, arg) == 0) 
    proc->tf->eax = 1; 
else { 
    cprintf("unknown call:"); 
    proc->tf->eax = -1; 
}
```

Comment: @JohnSilvester The address is actually passed in _EAX_ so it is in `proc->tf->eax`. See my updated code with some changes to your kernel code.

Comment: Worked like a charm sir! you are a star. Thanks!